# iMacro If Else Statement

Tags: if-statement, imacros

i tried to make an if else Statement in imacros but im Kind of lost.

This one checks if the buttons appear and if they appear it clicks them
basically its built up like this:

```
refresh
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN FORM=ACTION:Select.aspx ATTR=TXT:Cart
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN FORM=ACTION:Select.aspx ATTR=TXT:Cart
TAG POS=3 TYPE=SPAN FORM=ACTION:Select.aspx ATTR=TXT:Cart
TAG POS=4 TYPE=SPAN FORM=ACTION:Select.aspx ATTR=TXT:Cart
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
```

now i want to tell the script that if at some Point this button appears:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:Error.aspx ATTR=NAME:Back
```

the script performs another Action.

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: you can use `javascript` to call `iim-script`, check return code and make decisions by `if...else...`.

Comment: can you give an example please? im really new to javasript and imacros.

Answer (score 0):

```
va macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="SET !ERRRORIGNORE YES"+"\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:link EXTRACT=HREF"+"\n";

ret=iimPlay(macro);

if(ret=<0)
{
alert("There was an error");
}
```

Here is one example of iMacros JS.